# How to modify design of a message box in InnoSetup?

Tags: inno-setup

How can I remove this white footer from the message box ? How to modify design of a message box in InnoSetup ?

[image: Inno Setup mesage box]

Comment: See also [Inno setup: color for modal and browse directory windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37072155/850848).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message box used by InnoSetup is the standard Windows Message Box.  The white footer is part of theme of Windows.  You can only remove it by changing your Windows theme / color scheme.