# Inno Setup: Color for modal and browse directory windows

Tags: inno-setup, modal-window

Is it possible to change inner background color for modal and browse directory windows in Inno Setup? In my case I want it should be white.

[image]

[image]

---

UPD: Same behaviour is on the inner pages of Inner Setup, but I've fixed it by setting `WizardForm.InnerPage.Color := clWhite;`

I'm using [VclStylesInno](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-plugins/wiki/Inno-Setup) for styling my installer with custom style spreadsheat.

Comment: And if you use `Amakrits.vsf` style, does it work? Because it does for me, as you can see on the screenshot in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As turned out, the reason was in the "Colors" option in Bitmap Designer, which I use to modify my installer style. This option makes some additional styling for controls:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the color of these in Inno Setup itself, except by a custom build of Inno Setup or some addon DLL (see below).

All you can do is to re-implement these dialogs from the scratch:

- For the "browse" dialog: Handle the `WizardForm.DirBrowseButton.OnClick` and use `CreateCustomForm` and `TFolderTreeView` to implement the browse dialog. Download Inno Setup code and copy the existing implementation from `SelFolderForm.pas`.

  For an example of handling `WizardForm.DirBrowseButton.OnClick`, see
  [How to display localized Program Files name (display name) during installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39657457/850848)
- For the "cancel" dialog: Implement the `CancelButtonClick` event function. Make sure you set `Confirm` to `False` to get rid of the default prompt. And implement your own. Again, use the `CreateCustomForm`.

It's a lot of work for a small gain. I'd not do it.

---

Instead, you can use [VCL Styles for Inno Setup](https://github.com/RRUZ/vcl-styles-plugins/wiki/Inno-Setup) (DLL) to style Inno Setup windows (including all modal dialogs).

[image]

Comment: I've added hint to use VCL styles.

Comment: I already use it. In my case form is totally white in VCL stylesheet and it's still has some grey color like above on modal windows. It also was grey on the wizard pages till I've set WizardForm.InnerPage.Color := clWhite;

Comment: In older version of VCL there was bug preventing correct painting all modal forms. It should be fixed in the most latest version.

Comment: @AlexanderSmith Well, that's an information you should have included in your question in the first place. Please edit your question accordingly. What style do you use?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I've found the answer - the problem was in [Bitmap designer](http://prntscr.com/b3lqln). It colors controls over existing style settings.

Comment: Can you post this as an answer to close this question?