# How to display localized Program Files name (display name) during installation?

Tags: inno-setup

I'm currently creating an installer, which has `Program Files` as its default installation directory. To do this, I used `{pf}`.

It's a German program and only used in Germany and while the installer is entirely in German during selection of the destination directory, setup still displays `C:\Program Files` instead of the localized name `C:\Programme`.

Is it possible to get it to display `C:\Programme` instead? Functionally everything works fine, the application is installed in `C:\Programme`. I'm just concerned a basic user may be confused by reading `C:\Program Files`.

EDIT: Further information: I know `C:\Programme` or any other localized name for `Program Files` is just a display name, the physical path is always `Program Files`. Doesn't matter which Windows version or what language Windows has. Yet I'd still like setup to display `C:\Programme` during installation.

My test machines are on Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inno Setup does not support that.

You would have to fake it. You can dynamically translate contents of the `DirEdit` to/from a display name as needed:

- translate to display name, when the "Select Destination Location" page is activated
- translate to physical path, when "Browse" button is clicked.
- translate to display name, when new path is selected.
- translate to physical path, when "Next" button is clicked.

```pascal
function ToDisplayName(Path: string): string;
begin
  Result := ???;
end;

function FromDisplayName(Path: string): string;
begin
  Result := ???;
end;

var
  DirBrowseButtonClickOrig: TNotifyEvent;
  OnSelectDir: Boolean;

procedure DirBrowseButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := FromDisplayName(WizardForm.DirEdit.Text);
  DirBrowseButtonClickOrig(Sender);
  WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := ToDisplayName(WizardForm.DirEdit.Text);
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  DirBrowseButtonClickOrig := WizardForm.DirBrowseButton.OnClick;
  WizardForm.DirBrowseButton.OnClick := @DirBrowseButtonClick;
  OnSelectDir := False;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectDir then
  begin
    OnSelectDir := True;
    WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := ToDisplayName(WizardForm.DirEdit.Text);
  end
    else
  begin
    if OnSelectDir then
    begin
      OnSelectDir := False;
      WizardForm.DirEdit.Text := FromDisplayName(WizardForm.DirEdit.Text);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

A tricky part is of course the implementation of the `ToDisplayName` and `FromDisplayName` functions.

A real native implementation would be pretty complex and it's even questionable if you can implement it with limited features of the Pascal Script (particularly a lack of pointers).

But for your specific needs, you can use something as trivial as:

```pascal
[CustomMessages]
ProgramFilesLocalized=Programme

[Code]

function ToDisplayName(Path: string): string;
begin
  StringChange(Path, '\Program Files', '\' + CustomMessage('ProgramFilesLocalized'));
  Result := Path;
end;

function FromDisplayName(Path: string): string;
begin
  StringChange(Path, '\' + CustomMessage('ProgramFilesLocalized'), '\Program Files');
  Result := Path;
end;
```

[image]

---

If you need a real implementation for converting to/from display name, consider asking a separate question.

Comment: Thank you. Quite a big workaround. Have to think about whether that's worthwhile. The main problem I have with this solution is that it's hard coded, meaning I would have to create and maintain serveral install routines depending on the languages used. While it's currently only used in Germany, the program may be used in other countries, so I need a different installer for each language, which isn't what I'm looking for. Still, thank you very much for your insight into this issue.

Comment: As I wrote, it's possible that the `ToDisplayName` and `FromDisplayName` can be implemented using WinAPI to be generic and work on any language. But that's a huge task worth a new question + Even if not, you do not need a different installer for each language. You can use a [custom message](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=custommessagessection), just as with any other custom message in the installer (you probably have some already).