# Pop dialog background form color

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to set the background grey form color on the pop dialogs to white as well.

The following changes the main dialog backgrounds to `clWhite`, but does not affect the popup boxes.

```
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.Color := clWhite;
end;
procedure InitializeUninstallProgressForm();
begin
  UninstallProgressForm.Color := clWhite;
end;
```

[image]

For this, I believe I need to add the appropriate modification to

```
procedure InitializeSetup();
begin
end;
```

Similarly I wonder if anything can be done about the folder selector.

[image]

Comment: See [Inno Setup: Color for modal and browse directory windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37072155/850848).

Comment: Looks like it's not so straightforward